# How to get fully associative array with Zend's fetchPairs()

Tags: php, zend-framework

My `PHP` code is as follows:

```
$pairs = $read->select()
    ->from($eavTable,array('value','entity_id'))
    ->where('attribute_id=?',$ddId)
    ->where('store_id=?','0')
    ->distinct(true);

return $read->fetchPairs($pairs);
```

this code returns a PHP Array with both string and integer keys. IE:

```
array(3) { 
    [40003]=> string(6) "246409" 
    ["rootcat"] => string(1) "2"
    ["10000000888"]=> string(6) "246410" 
}
```

I guess string is returned when the value is longer than 8 bytes, or when the value is not numeric.
How can I "instruct" Zend to return fully associative array? so that `40003` would also be treated as string? 
In database, these values are marked as varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  In PHP, if the index is represented exactly as an integer (up to `PHP_INT_MAX`), then it is an integer index even if you attempt to stringify it in quotes:

```
$array['40003'] = "246409";
$array['40003x'] = "246409";
var_dump($array);
```

---

```
array(2) {
  [40003]=>
  string(6) "246409"
  ["40003x"]=>
  string(6) "246409"
}
```

---

Or by type cast:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $result[strval($key)] = $value;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Same output.

Or by other trickery:

```
echo serialize($array);
// a:1:{i:40003;s:6:"246409";}

//change to string index
$result = unserialize('a:1:{s:5:"40003";s:6:"246409";}');
var_dump($result);
```

Same output.